# Granting Library permissions to external users using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

Is there a possibility of inviting external users by e-mail and granting them collaborate permissions using the SharePoint REST API? (See the picture for reference) I have successfully managed to stop inheriting permissions using an API call but now I am stuck with this issue. All the articles I came across on the Internet explain how to grant permissions to internal users but not via an invite using an e-mail address.

Any help much appreciated.

[image: Library Permissions]